# Getting camera input from user in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, camera

I have a problem. I'm making a Flask application that requires camera input, which is sent to `opencv`, and then I process it and return an image. I have no problem with the streaing. My issue here is the fact that I need to access the user's webcam, and give the information to Flask so it can process the image, and THEN return it. To do this, I need access to the user's webcam. I imagine something like this:

*main.py*

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from myapp import process #Import function to process image
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/webcam", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def camera():
    if request.method == "POST":
        image = request.get_json()['image']
        result = process(image) #Process image
        return result
    else:
        return('camera.html') #Return camera site

#Other code/functions...
```

Then in the html file, I'd have a `<script>` tag with the script to send a post request with the image.
(If there is a better way to do this, tell me.)

I don't know how to get the image to the user, though, in a way that OpenCV can process it.

Comment: I'm unsure what your question actually is, but you can ask the user for access to the camera through `mediaDevices`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices / https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera

Comment: I know, but I can't figure out how to send that data to Flask itself.

Comment: I know I could take the image and convert it to a string, but that string is virtually useless, as I don't know how to process the resulting HTMLVideoElement.

Comment: You'll capture and submit as base64 to your server, then decode the base64 string there.

Comment: I would still, after decoding, need it in a format the OpenCV could process.

Comment: For example, if it could send a jpg image...

Comment: Yes, as shown in the second link above you copy the image into a canvas. You can then retrieve the content as jpeg by doing `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Comment: few examples on GitHub: [python-examples/flask/web camera in browser - canvas - take image and upload to server](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/flask/web%20camera%20in%20browser%20-%20canvas%20-%20take%20image%20and%20upload%20to%20server) There are also examples which get image from browser, send to flask, process it with cv2 and send back to browser.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing, taking the image, sending it to Flask, processing it with cv2, and sending it back to the browser.